# How to make a timer with 2 functions, one for the time in and one for the time out

Tags: python, timer

I want to make 2 functions for employee to clock in at the start of work and clock out out at the end of work. What is the best way to do it? Using my method it seems that the timer literally doesn't count at all outputs 0

```
import time
from datetime import datetime


def time_in(employee_id): 
    time_in = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y on %H:%M:%S")
    print(f"""Employee ID:{employee_id}
You have logged in on {time_in}
          """)
    start = time.time()
    return start, employee_id
    


x,y = time_in(123)


def time_out(start, employee_id):
    stop = time.time()
    seconds_worked = stop - start
    ty_res = time.gmtime(seconds_worked)
    time_worked = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",ty_res)
    time_out = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y on %H:%M:%S")
    print(f"""Employee ID:{employee_id}
You have logged out on {time_out}""")

    return time_worked, employee_id


print(time_out(x, y))

while True:
    user = input("""what is your action:
'in' for time in
'out' for time out
'quit' to quit
""")
    if user == 'in':
        eid = input('employee id: ')
        time_in(eid)
    elif user == 'out':
        eid = input('employee id: ')
        x,y = time_in(int(eid))
        print(time_out(x,y))
    elif user == "quit":
        break
```

Comment: You need to store the start times somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This code makes the time zero:

```
    elif user == 'out':
        eid = input('employee id: ')
        x,y = time_in(int(eid))
        print(time_out(x,y))
```

You register a time_in() right before the time_out(). That results in less than a second of time (virtually 0).

Instead use this code:

```
    if user == 'in':
        eid = input('employee id: ')
        x,y = time_in(int(eid))
    elif user == 'out':
        eid = input('employee id: ')
        print(time_out(x,y))
    elif user == "quit":
        break
```